# How to get rid of $injector type errors in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have the following in my AngularJS Code:

```
this.$injector.get('$state').current.name !== 'login'
```

However, it throws me an error of:

> error TS2339: Property 'current' does not exist on type '{}'.

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried this:

```
export namespace NewInjector extends angular.auto.IInjectorService {
    current: any;
};
```

without any success.

Comment: Maybe you need to define a function called `get` that returns an object with the property `current` in it on that interface.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the injector the get method should already return any. http://definitelytyped.org/docs/oclazyload--oclazyload/interfaces/ng.auto.iinjectorservice.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value returned by `get()` method of the `$injector` is any.. which does not have **`current`** property... so we just have to assert the compiler, that we know what will be returned *(instead of `any`)*

```
var state = this.$injector.get('$state') as ng.ui.IStateService;
var isNotLogin = state.current.name !== "login";
...
```

Another notation

```
var state = this.$injector.get<ng.ui.IStateService>('$state');
```

And a quick overview of the `IInjectorService`

```
interface IInjectorService {
    ...
    get<T>(name: string, caller?: string): T;
    ...
```

Comment: I had no idea that I can use this syntax. Thats really sweet! Thanks!